# DDS participant doesnt unregisters itself immediately when terminated

Tags: data-distribution-service, ros2

I have observed that even if i stop a node or a participant by pressing ctr + C, i.e. terminate it...it still shows in the Admin console or 2 minutes or so. Why isnt it immediately derigestered. Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At shutdown of your application, you should clean up the DDS entities, as demonstrated in [this piece of example code](https://github.com/rticommunity/rticonnextdds-examples/blob/master/examples/keyed_data/c/keys_publisher.c#L65). In a nutshell, it invokes the following methods:

```
DDS_DomainParticipant_delete_contained_entities(participant);
DDS_DomainParticipantFactory_delete_participant(DDS_TheParticipantFactory, participant);
```

If you do not do that, the DDS discovery process will detect by itself after a while that the Participant has gone. The responsiveness of this mechanism is configurable, as explained in the knowledge base article [What settings affect DomainParticipant’s liveliness?](https://community.rti.com/kb/what-settings-affect-domainparticipant%E2%80%99s-liveliness)

Now pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> normally will not execute the code described above, because the signal will terminate the process right away. As far as I know, the only way to avoid that is to install a signal handler that invokes that clean-up functionality. Here is a gist with some example code on how to install a signal handler: [aspyct/signal.c](https://gist.github.com/aspyct/3462238).